# local server not able to find the welcome.jsp file in sprin web mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

[Project link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UfxnML6yoVSdWyEnGKJO4ugclTDw9A2N)

I am doing a spring web-mvc app using maven and tomcat server. So the problem is after clicking on the link of the index.jsp, it is not redirecting to welcome.jsp.

```
controller class

package com.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

public class controller {

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
 public String redirect()  
{  
    return "welcome";  
}  }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance..." 
version="4.0">
<display-name>CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping></web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html><head><title>Spring MVC Tutorial Series by Crunchify.com</title>
<h3><a href="welcome">Click here to See Welcome Message... /></h3>
</div></body></html>
```

Welcome.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "ht
<html><head>
<title>Spring MVC Tutorial by Crunchify - Hello World Spring MVC
Example</title></head><body>

Spring MCV Tutorial by <a href="https://crunchify.com">Crunchify</a>.
Click <a href="https://crunchify.com/category/java-tutorials/"
target="_blank">here</a> for all Java and <a
href='https://crunchify.com/category/spring-mvc/' 
target='_blank'>here</a>
for all Spring MVC, Web Development examples.<br>
</div></body></html>
```

crunchify-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=..."

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan
base-package="com.controller" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<bean id="viewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/"></property>  
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>          
</bean> </beans>
```

This is my directory structure. i am not getting how to go to welcome.jsp.
[image: Directory Strucutre]

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me?? Why it is not redirecting to the welcome.jsp??

Comment: [XML view Resolver](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-xmlviewresolver-example/)

Please se this tutorial , maybe you will get some help.

Comment: You need to add the `@Controller` annotation to your controller class otherwise it will not be picked up by component scan `<context:component-scan
base-package="com.controller" />`and therefore will not be registered with the Spring MVC framework.

Comment: hi @AlanHay , i have missed that. Thanks for telling me, but the result is same. Can you again tell me where am i going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your index.jsp

```
<h3><a href="welcome">Click here to See Welcome Message... /></h3>
```

You are mentioning direct `welcome` in `anchor` which wouldn't work here.

Use is like that

- use `<form action="page2.jsp">`

**or**

submit to a servlet using

```
<form action="targetServlet">,
```

and then:

redirect to page2, using `response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp")`

or

forward to page2, using `request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp").forward()`